# How stable is Web API connected with Access DB (2000 mdb)?

Tags: angularjs, ms-access, asp.net-web-api, database-connection

I am working on replacing an application with Angular front end and webAPI(MVC4). The data for this application is provided by third party in access 2000 (mdb) and change frequently. Also some of the calculation from this database is done with Third party libraries too. So initial decision was to maintain the db in Access (primarily because we don't want to touch this third party library used for calculation and db change is driven by research org too) but more I am reading- it is not [recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database). At this moment - I am not sure about how to connect either (JET OLEDB). Almost feels like we need to change the scope but knowing others experiences will be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a SO help question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem will be that Access has a very low limit for number of connections and it is very easy to exceed that.  You're much better off using something like SQL Express which to be clear still has a low limit for connections but is still better than Access.  Access you will also deal with file locks when writing.